# How do I setup maven sub-projects with inter-dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm having a hard time setting up a set of related maven projects with interdependencies between them.

Here's my simplified case:

```
pom.xml     -- parent pom
\base\
    pom.xml
    src\main\java\Base.java     -- this is just a simple class
\derived\
    pom.xml
    src\main\java\Derived.java  -- this is a simple class that needs Base class to compile successfully, and has a main function
```

My goals are:

1. be able to compile, on my machine, all projects:

   - i.e. `mnv clean compile` is successful in \
2. be able to compile, on my machine, just one project:

   - i.e. `mnv clean compile` is successful in \base\ and \derived\ (though this may not work by design: [Inter Project Dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970231/inter-project-dependencies-in-maven))

     *[edit: found the answer for this one: base needs to be published locally before derived in compiled: i.e. in \base, do `mvn clean compile install` instead of doing just doing `mvn clean compile`. Once this is done, doing `mvn clean compile` in \derived works fine. Still, it would be great to do this without touching global state, i.e. without having to install base -- so if anyone knows a way of achieving this, please add it as an answer]*
3. be able to run derived project on my machine (mvn exec:run or equivalent) direcly from the source tree:

   - i.e. `mvn exec:run` in \derived\ should compile (if needed) and run the derived.jar
4. the "shared component" use case: push the base artifact to the shared repository, where other people can consume it as a maven dependency (i.e. compile time dependency):

   - i.e. `mvn clean compile ???` will push this to the shared repository specified in ~/.m2/config.xml
5. the "image directory" use case: push the derived artifact and its depedencies to a local directory, where it can be run via "java -jar ..." or it can exposed as an ftp/http share for other people to get it. I.e., use cases like those:

   - `mvn clean compile ???` will push derived.jar and dependencies (like base.jar) to ~/.m2/maven.repo/.../derived or equivalent, and then I can cd ~/.m2/maven.repo/.../derived and run `java -jar derived.jar` to run it.
   - `mvn clean compile ???` will push base.jar to ~/.m2/maven.repo/.../base (or derived.jar to its corresponding dir), which is already exposed as a download point via local web or ftp server.

How do I do the goals above?

Here's the relevant section from parent pom:

```
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>parentpom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>parentpom</name>

<modules>
    <module>base</module>
    <module>derived</module>
</modules>
...
```

Here's the relevant section from base pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentpom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo.base</groupId>
<artifactId>base</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>base</name>
...
```

Here's the relevant section from derived pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentpom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo.derived</groupId>
<artifactId>derived</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>derived</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, what exactly is not working in case of (1)?

Comment: The main reason for (1) it was a naming inconsistency in my maven configuration: instead of using everywhere FooColorBlack, I sometimes reverted the parts to FooBlackColor (made up example, not real names).

Comment: Here is an example project explained: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your parent pom looks good but your module/derived poms don't: There are several issues which will produce some problems etc.

First you are using different groupId's for the derived/base module. If you have a [multi-module](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) build you shouldn't do this. Furthermore, the version of derived/base is inherited by the parent and shouldn't be set explicit which means you should have something like the following:

```
<modelVersion>...</...>
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentpom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>base</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>base</name>
```

The groupId is usually inherited. But sometimes you have a larger number of modules that may be sub-modules of sub-modules which results in a structure like this:

```
+--- parent (pom.xml)
       +--- mod1 (pom.xml)
              +--- mod11 (pom.xml)
              +--- mod12 (pom.xml)
       +--- mod2 (pom.xml)
```

In Such cases, the mod1 itself is a a pom packaging module:

```
<modelVersion>...</...>
...
<groupId>com.company.project<groupId>  
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
  <module>mod1</module>
  <module>mod2</module>
</modules>
```

mod1:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.project<groupId>  
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.project.mod1</groupId>
<artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>mod11</module>
  <module>mod12</module>
</modules>
```

mod11:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.project.mod1</groupId>
    <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mod11</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>mod11</module>
  <module>mod12</module>
</modules>
```

If you need to make a dependency between modules the solution is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.project.mod1</groupId>
    <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mod11</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <!-- This shouldn't be a dep which is packaging: pom -->
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

To compile the whole project with all sub modules in one just go to parent folder and:

mvn clean package

will compile etc. If you like to compile only a single project you can do this by (from parent):

```
mvn -pl mod1
```

which will work only if you have installed the whole project once before. Another solution is:

```
mvn -am -pl mod1
```

To make the artifacts acessible for others the simplest solution is to install a repository manager and do:

mvn deploy

All others can use and artifact as a SNAPSHOT dependency.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with such a detailed answer!  

The "which will work only if you have installed the whole project once before" part was the key for my errors.
I sometimes deleted out files from my local repo as a way to clean-up and ensure some sort of baseline (later, I found out that SNAPSHOOT in name is treated as a special case) and this expains why sometimes I get a failures while other I don't.

Comment: I really liked `${project.version}` tip